# Ranked order list of edges using opencv

Tags: visual-c++, opencv, image-processing

I am doing following steps which has shown in attached image. How can i do raked order list of edges in opencv? Does any one have any idea?
I am beginner of opencv and image processing field. 
Thanks .......

Comment: Where is the image you are talking about ?

Answer (score 0):

This is for Hough lines?  If so, I believe they are already rank ordered in the vector that is returned.